# Hibernate requires begin and commit for read

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate needs a beginTransaction and commitTransaction for a simple database read, else it leads to inconsistency in the data being returned by the select query. Why is a commit required, what changes are made in a read query?

Answer (score 1):

commitTransaction simply closes the current transaction (which should be either committed or rolled back).